# ggplotly() is overriding some ggplot theme() arguments. Does anyone know how to stop this?

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggplotly

basically I want my plot backgrounds to be the same color as the meta plot, which isnt executed when I use ggplotly() wrapper. image with (first) and without  ggplotly. code below:

```
#ggplotly(
        df %>%
        filter(!is.na(Boxoffice)&!is.na(Decade))%>%
        ggplot(aes(x=Boxoffice,y=IMDb.Score))+
        geom_point(aes(text=Title),size=2,alpha=0.3,color = "#DB5461")+
        theme_aes()+
        facet_wrap(~Decade)+
        theme_aes()+
        theme(plot.background = element_rect(fill="#f0f0f0",color="#b4b4b4"))
        #)
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: what is `theme_aes()` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove background again from plot_ly object;

```
library(tidyverse)
library(plotly)


iris %>%
ggplot(aes(x=Sepal.Width,y=Sepal.Length))+
geom_point(size=2,alpha=0.3,color = "#DB5461")+
facet_wrap(~Species)+
theme(plot.background = element_rect(fill="#f0f0f0",color="#b4b4b4"),panel.background = element_blank()) -> ggobj

plotlyobj <- ggplotly(ggobj)


ggobj

plotlyobj %>%layout(plot_bgcolor='rgba(0,0,0,0)')
```